# Multiple values in same key in an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm new to PHP. But i'm trying to assign multiple values in a key in an array and i'm having trouble with it. What am i doing wrong?

```
$skill_groups = array(
            'combat' => 'Attack', 'Defence', 'Strength', '', 'Ranged', 'Magic',
            'gathering' =>  'Mining', 'Woodcutting', 'Fishing', 'Hunter', 'Farming', 'Divination',
            'artisan' =>  'Smithing', 'Cooking', 'Runecrafting', 'Crafting', 'Firemaking', 'Herblore', 'Fletching', 'Construction',
            'support' => 'Dungeoneering', 'Thieving', 'Agility', 'Slayer', 'Prayer', 'Constitution'
);
```

Comment: *One* key always maps to exactly *one* value. There can't be multiple values. (In a plain PHP array anyway). The question is, how do you want to use this array and its values? Would it make sense to use a nested array?

Comment: I just want to be able to group them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create *Multidimensional Array*. Right syntax will be like

```
$skill_groups = array(
        'combat' => array('Attack', 'Defence', 'Strength', '', 'Ranged', 'Magic'),
        'gathering' =>  array('Mining', 'Woodcutting', 'Fishing', 'Hunter', 'Farming', 'Divination'),
        'artisan' =>  array('Smithing', 'Cooking', 'Runecrafting', 'Crafting', 'Firemaking', 'Herblore', 'Fletching', 'Construction'),
        'support' => array('Dungeoneering', 'Thieving', 'Agility', 'Slayer', 'Prayer', 'Constitution'));
```

And access element like this:

```
print_r($skill_groups['combat']); // something like array([0] => 'Attack', [1] => 'Defence', [2] => 'Strength', [3] => '', [4] => 'Ranged', [5] => 'Magic')
echo $skill_groups['combat'][0]; // 'Attack'
```